# Memory usage increasing when I use gradient and border simultaneously

Tags: css, google-chrome

When I'm scrolling this page http://jsfiddle.net/n7uhra4b/, memory usage in Chrome (in Chrome task manager) continuously increasing. Hovewer, if I will comment this line:

```
border: 1px solid red;
```

memory is not increasing? Why this is happening?

Comment: Just a thought but does the same thing happen if you set `background-clip` to `padding-box`?

Comment: Aw. I thought it could be related to the border being drawn over the gradient. Worth a shot. Sorry I couldn't be of more help than that.